# Flask-admin : flask.ext.admin.contrib.sqla - ModelView - form validate

Tags: flask, flask-admin

First, I have tried to use form_base_class to configure validate methods for my admin view :

```
class MyForm(Form):

    def validate_name(self, field):
        pass

class MyView(ModelView):

    form_base_class = MyForm
```

But the edit form and create form is then the same.

Then I tried to use the create_form and edit_form methods, but it seems there is no consequences :

```
admin = Admin(app,  name='Admin')
myView = MyView(Test, db.session)
myView.create_form(MyCreateForm)
myView.edit_form(MyMEditForm)
admin.add_view(myView)
```

So how can we validate flask-admin forms with different test for the edit and create ?

Comment: Why do you want different validation rules?

Comment: for the creation : i want to test that the name is not already used in the base. For the edit, the user can change the id or the name, so the validation of the name is then different, because it is already used once.

Comment: By "id" do you mean the primary key?

Comment: yes, id is the primary key.

Comment: My two pieces of advice are: 1. left the database enforce uniqueness and 2. don't change your primary keys